# Wireguard-OpenVPN Chaining

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, iptables, wireguard

I'm trying to chain a wireguard server with an OpenVPN server (better latency & performance issues on mobile)

Basically, `wg client > wg server/ovpn client > ovpn server (commercial)`

I've tried a few things, and actually got it working once, but I couldn't reproduce it after a reboot.

Current wg0 server config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = [redacted]
Address = 10.6.0.1/24
MTU = 1420
ListenPort = 34347



[Peer]
PublicKey = [redacted]
PresharedKey = [redacted]
AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.2/32
```

Network interface (of middleman server) is eth0, with a gateway of 192.168.9.1 (this is a home network, but forwarded for external access)

The obvious solution would be to send all packets from the wireguard server to tun0, but I'm unsure of how to go about that.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would add `Table=off` under `[Interface]` of the *server* conf if you use `wg-quick` to set it up.

Then, one of the ways is:

```
ip route add default dev tun0 table 123
ip rule add iif wg0 table 123
```

This will make all traffics (IIRC that should be forwarded) coming from the `wg0` interface look up route table `123` (it can be any unused number) for route, and the table has been made to consists of a default route that leads to `tun0`.

You can add them as `PreUp` under `[Interface]`, again if you use `wg-quick`. Better use the equivalent in OpenVPN though since the route adding requires `tun0` to exist. (Or you can make sure the WireGuard is started after the OpenVPN by some means (`systemctl edit` or whatever).

If your OpenVPN is already adding a default route to the route table `main`, and you want to keep it that way for some reason, you'll need another approach, namely to "blacklist" the *encapsulated* WireGuard traffics from going into the OpenVPN tunnel.

For example:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.9.1 dev eth0 onlink table 321
ip rule add iif lo ipproto udp sport 34347 table 321
```

---

Either way you'll need to do source NAT for the traffics from the WireGuard client(s):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.6.0.0/24 -o tun0 -J MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Appreciate it so much, even though I'm a bit late. Thanks for the help, works wonderfully for my use case.